# How to get previous value of field in ant design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a following field in as part of my form.

```
          <Col span={18}>
            <Form.Item
              name="name"
              label="Name"
              colon={false}
              validateTrigger={"onBlur"}
              hasFeedback
              rules={[
                {
                  validator: nameValidator,
                  message: 'Name is not unique',
                },
              ]}
              labelCol={{ span: 2 }}
              wrapperCol={{ span: 22 }}
            >
               <Input placeholder="Enter name" />
            </Form.Item>
          </Col>
```

what i want to achieve is validation not to be triggered every time i focus and blur on my field without changing value of it.
Is there any ways of getting previous value of the field ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you describe can be achieved by `validateTrigger="onChange"` - no need to access a previous value.

Comment: but implementation using onBlur is required by my task

Comment: then why do you write in your question: "what i want to achieve is validation not to be triggered every time i focus and blur on my field without changing value of it"?

Comment: because that is what i need